# Spring Dataflow concepts clarification

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I started using Spring Dataflow, and I find myself with some questions I'm unable to answer, reading the documentation, and doing some testing. Any clarification would be welcomed (if you can't answer all of them at once, answer those you can, I'll consolidate the full answer if need be)

1. Spring Dataflow is meant to write applicative workflows, like: the output of `app A` is the input of `app B`, and so on. Workflows do not need to be linear, as output of `app A` may be the input of both `app B` and `app C`. **Is that accurate** ?
2. It is well written that apps in the flow pipeline communicate in a "message-driven" way. `App A` sends a message to a broker (like RabbitMQ or Kafka, for instance), and `app B` consumes the message from it. We can have multiple different brokers in our flow. But is the messaging the only way to send information between applications ? **Is it possible that `app A` calls `app B` through an HTTP REST request, for instance ? And if so, how ?**
3. Since applications rely on asynchronous messaging (see above question), what is the Dataflow's added value ? I mean that if you configure `app A` to send messages to the `foo` topic, and `app B` to consume messages from the very same topic, you could deploy both separately (without Dataflow), and it'll work. From what I understand, Dataflow only provides a way to deploy and undeploy them all at once, rather than one by one. **Is that correct ?**
4. Like the previous question, the asynchronous messaging abstracts you from defining a flow order (i.e. you could start `app B` before `app A`). The whole system will only work when both applications are up, but they do not even need to know each others. The only needed thing is that they use the same broker and topic, one to send the message, the other to get it. So **why do you absolutely need to link one application's output to another one's input, in Spring Cloud Dataflow ? This is a way to force both applications use the same topic, but is that all** ?

Answer (score 6):

> Spring Dataflow is meant to write applicative workflows

Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) is an orchestration service that allows you to compose microservice applications into a coherent pipeline. The applications accepted (*today*) are either based on Spring Cloud Stream (SCSt) or Spring Cloud Task (SCT) programming model, so you can orchestrate streaming and task/batch pipelines respectively. Depending on the requirements, you could operationalize linear or complex DAG-type workflows.

> But is the messaging the only way to send information between applications ?

Right now, yes. The current binder abstraction provided by SCSt supports messaging channels and we are in the process of generalizing the binding model. The next generation is evolving into also adding support for *KStream* as input/output and as well as Reactor's *Flux* as input/output. We don't have support for RESTful binding mechanism yet.

> Since applications rely on asynchronous messaging (see above question), what is the Dataflow's added value ?

You can orchestrate individual SCSt/SCT apps. The standalone apps include properties such as "binder connection information", "channel binding destinations" and among many others - you're expected to supply them. Once you have requirements such as partitioning and scaling, you'd have to bookkeep even more of those application properties. This is where SCDF's orchestration layer adds value. Apart from the DSL, REST-APIs, Dashboard/Flo, that you can use for quicker creation of streaming/batch pipelines, SCDF also automates the creation of those known properties to connect the apps with well-defined naming conventions.

> Dataflow only provides a way to deploy and undeploy them all at once, rather than one by one. Is that correct ?

If you deploy a stream with a set of apps, SCDF deploys them in an order. You could undeploy, destroy, and query for aggregated status of the stream made of apps. And, for Tasks, you can launch, destroy and query for execution status etc.

> why do you absolutely need to link one application's output to another one's input, in Spring Cloud Dataflow ?

This is not clear. For stream processing, you'd need a minimum of 2-apps (*source and sink*) in SCDF's context. You can, however, build an [aggregate application](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_aggregation) using SCSt and orchestrate the aggregation (source, processor(*s*) and sink) as a single unit, too.

Comment: Thanks for those great answers, Sabby, it definitely helps. Although, I'm still not clear on some points : in a event-driven architecture, why would you need to deploy applications in a specific order ? And if my application registers a Sink binding (through the `@EnableBinding` and `@ServiceActivator` mechanism), why I can't I deploy it alone in SCDF (this is actually the last point you told wasn't clear enough) ? From my understanding, it'll poll the messaging service regularly as it, without the need of SCDF. So why do I need to add a tap as a source to be able to save the stream anyway ?

Comment: We deploy apps in order (_i.e: consumer first and then producers_) only to make sure that the consumer(s) are ready and available to handle the messages as soon as the producers come up. It doesn't have to be this way in the messaging architecture, but it is really just for cleaner processing and convenience.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth it to mention that the new SCDF execution model and overall architecture are limiting for some use-cases where most of us belong to (at least TELCO environment we operate on). In other words, SCDF running on top of the container engine is near future - somewhere. We have working SpringXD in production and it works like a charm with the Zookeeper (distributed). Now, with SCDF concept I must think of something else, despite the fact that I've managed to install and run SCDF on Kubernetes cluster (in my lab).